# Is a Linear mixed model the same thing as logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, model, linear

Im studying for a statistics test and the book pages talk about linear mixed models, so adding random effects in this case. Then in the reviewing lecture that no longer is mentioned but instead we are to understand logistic regression.

Are these the same thing? Can linear regression be performed for a linear mixed model? im just slightly confused about the whole terminology because a big part of this test will be multiple choice

Comment: In case it helps with sorting out the terminology, logistic regression is a special case of the _generalized_ linear model, and in turn of the generalized linear mixed model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, linear mixed models are not the same as logistic regression.

Linear mixed models have a continuous dependent variable, logistic regression models have dichotomous dependent variables (or, ordinal ones for ordinal logistic and categorical ones for multinomial logistic).

Linear mixed models are one way of dealing with violation of the assumption of independent errors.